# Import multiple hosts in zabbix

Tags: xml, excel, zabbix

i have a list of about 270 entries with names, IP and description in an excel table - all of those i want to add in zabbix (templates and group is always the same). i first thought that there has to be a rather easy way to add multiple hosts with xml, but i cant seem to combine my excel table with a compatible xml file - i tried exporting a single host from zabbix, then opening this xml file with excel, then fill in the data and export as xml again. sadly, this did not work, as i can either not export the file at all or the output xml file will only consist of the first row. does anyone know whats the way to go here? would save me a buttload of work, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize [zabbix api](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/api/reference/host/create) to do this. Write a small script using your preferred language utilizing zabbix module in them
For example in ruby [zabbix api gem](https://github.com/express42/zabbixapi/blob/master/examples/Hosts.md). Similarly you can see modules in respective language. You can write script which will read from your excel or CSV file  and call api function to create host